# column order relevant in df.to_sql(if_exists="append")?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, pandas-to-sql

I was wondering, whether `df.to_sql("db_table", con=some_engine, if_exists="append")` requires that the order of the columns of `df` (a dataframe) and `db_table` (a database table) has to be the same. There is nothing about it in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_sql), so I tried it out. The result is that the order doesn't have to be the same. However, where can I find out whether the order has to match, without trying an example code? How can I find the location where it is revealed what if_exists="append" does (for example, in PyCharm)?

Comment: Please re-phrase your question. I do not quite understand. Order may never matter. If question is about documentation consider posting a question to pandas-dev team as an issue.

Answer (score 2):

According to underlying pandas code for the [SQL IO module](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/io/sql.py), insertion of records are handled in an SQLAchemy [**`Connection.execute`**](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.execute) call with parameters as a list of dictionaries:

```py
def _execute_insert(self, conn, keys: list[str], data_iter) -> int:
    """
    Execute SQL statement inserting data

    Parameters
    ----------
    conn : sqlalchemy.engine.Engine or sqlalchemy.engine.Connection
    keys : list of str
       Column names
    data_iter : generator of list
       Each item contains a list of values to be inserted
    """
    data = [dict(zip(keys, row)) for row in data_iter]
    result = conn.execute(self.table.insert(), data)
    return result.rowcount
```

Additionally, the `self.table.insert()` noticeably omits the `values()` call where SQLAlchemy [`insert` docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/dml.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.insert) indicate `values` clause is dynamically rendered based on parameters passed within `Connection.execute`:

> **values** – collection of values to be inserted; see `Insert.values()` for a description of allowed formats here. Can be omitted entirely; a Insert construct will also dynamically render the VALUES clause at execution time based on the parameters passed to `Connection.execute()`.

Altogether, the `DataFrame.to_sql` uses named parameters (not positional parameters using `?` or `%s` placeholders) in underlying insert-values SQL query. Therefore, order of DataFrame columns does not matter since the execution will dynamically align key-value pairs to corresponding columns of the database SQLAlchemy Table.